# How to download an excel file sent from the c# Controller to Ajax Response

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have been trying to download a file that I return in the following controller method

```
 [HttpGet]
    public FileResult TestGenerateFile(Guid[] userIDs, Guid reportID)
    {
        Guid reportRunID = Guid.NewGuid();

        ViewBase.LoadViewBase();
        IMVCWebPage page = ViewBase.MVCWebPage;

        string filePath = manager.GenerateTestFile(reportRunID, reportID, page.SelectedItemID.Value, userIDs);

        System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open);

        fileStream.Flush();

        return File(fileStream, "application/vnd.ms-excel", Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    }
```

, however every time I have managed to get a save as dialog using Blob(data) in my ajax success method, my excel file gives a warning when being opened and the file has many weird characters, as follow:

[image: Corrupted excel File Screenshot]

I can also see from the developer tools that the request was successful, and if I copy the URL from the developer tools and run it in a separate tab (or open in new tab), the file is downloaded correctly without any corrupted data.

The ajax code:

```
testReportOutputFileGeneration: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: window.applicationVirtualPath + '/Reports/TestGeneratefile',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                data: {
                    userIDs: userIDs.value,
                    reportID: $("#lblreport_id").text()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });

                    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    window.open(objectUrl);

                },
                error: function () { console.log("Error")}
            });
        },
```

so my question is: is there a way to enhance this ajax to prompt the user with a Save As dialog and get the excel saved correctly without any weird characters? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look into ``Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my_filename"`` HTTP header usage. Your HTTP response should include that header to prompt the user to save the file.

Comment: Hi @uncoder - the content disposition is automatically sent down from the controller - i have checked the headers on the response and I can confirm this is already there: [link](http://i66.tinypic.com/k9jd7c.jpg) - I discovered this as i tried previously to set it manually and had an error about having a duplicate header.

Comment: Well, I am not sure about Ajax then in this case. Why do you need it at all? Can't you use ``window.location.replace`` instead? What also bothers me is that you're specifying the content type on the client while it should come from the server.